# Extracting date from a string in Python

Tags: python, string, date

How can I extract the date from a string like "monkey 2010-07-10 love banana"? Thanks!

Comment: Just a hint: it starts and ends with a digit. Let me think about that. Although, regex can be your friend there.

Comment: `.isdigit()` @HamishGrubijan is an implementation, though my answer below discusses this in detail with modules for ease.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If the date is given in a fixed form, you can simply use a regular expression to extract the date and "datetime.datetime.strptime" to parse the date:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

match = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', text)
date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Otherwise, if the date is given in an arbitrary form, you can't extract it easily.

Comment: What if it is in European format, such as 20/01/1980 meaning "Jan 20 1980"? What if months/days/years fall outside of reasonable range?

Comment: @lunaryorn In the first statement does "re" refer to the string where we are seaching for our desired pattern?

Comment: @vishal.k It refers to the built-in `re` module, ie, `import re`.

Comment: In case someone else made same mistake: you need to `from datetime import datetime` instead of `import datetime`

Answer (score 195):

Using [python-dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html):

```
In [1]: import dateutil.parser as dparser

In [18]: dparser.parse("monkey 2010-07-10 love banana",fuzzy=True)
Out[18]: datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 10, 0, 0)
```

Invalid dates raise a `ValueError`:

```
In [19]: dparser.parse("monkey 2010-07-32 love banana",fuzzy=True)
# ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

It can recognize dates in many formats:

```
In [20]: dparser.parse("monkey 20/01/1980 love banana",fuzzy=True)
Out[20]: datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 20, 0, 0)
```

Note that it makes a guess if the date is ambiguous:

```
In [23]: dparser.parse("monkey 10/01/1980 love banana",fuzzy=True)
Out[23]: datetime.datetime(1980, 10, 1, 0, 0)
```

But the way it parses ambiguous dates is customizable:

```
In [21]: dparser.parse("monkey 10/01/1980 love banana",fuzzy=True, dayfirst=True)
Out[21]: datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 10, 0, 0)
```

Comment: @Hamish: If there are two dates (as in the case of `"monkey 10/01/1980 love 7/10/2010 banana"`), it may raise a ValueError, or (as in the case of `"monkey 10/01/1980 love 2010-07-10 banana"`) it may misinterpret the second date as denoting hours, minutes, seconds or timezone. `fuzzy=True` gives it license to guess.

Comment: @unutbu str = "By flufie                Â· October 14, 2010 at 11:22 pm                Â· 26 replies"  By using dateutil i am getting "ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
"

Comment: what happens if there are more than 1 date in the text?

Comment: @alvas: The `parse` function may raise an exception (even if `fuzzy=True`), or with `fuzzy=True`, it may return the first date or a mish-mash composed of parts of both dates. So really, `parse` should only be called on a string containing one date.

Comment: is it possible to get the index of the characters that forms the date when using fuzzy?

Comment: @Kailegh: Yes, it would be possible to *deduce* the indices using [fuzzy_with_tokens=True](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse). If you'd like more clarification, please start a new question.

Comment: It matches single numbers!

Answer (score 40):

For extracting the date from a string in Python; the best module available is the [datefinder](https://datefinder.readthedocs.io) module.

You can use it in your Python project by following the easy steps given below.

### Step 1: Install datefinder Package

```
pip install datefinder
```

### Step 2: Use It In Your Project

```
import datefinder

input_string = "monkey 2010-07-10 love banana"
# a generator will be returned by the datefinder module. I'm typecasting it to a list. Please read the note of caution provided at the bottom.
matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(input_string))

if len(matches) > 0:
    # date returned will be a datetime.datetime object. here we are only using the first match.
    date = matches[0]
    print date
else:
    print 'No dates found'
```

**note:** if you are expecting a large number of matches; then typecasting to list won't be a recommended way as it will be having a big performance overhead.

Comment: I found that `datefinder` handed ambiguous date matching better than `python-dateutil` returning only two possible dates from a random medium.com blog post as opposed to five. Not sure how it handles different locales however...

Comment: This is pretty good, except it somehow doesnt work when there is a colon(:) before date string:

`string = "Assessment Date: 17-May-2017 at 13:31"`

`list(datefinder.find_dates(string.lower()))`
`#[]`

`string = "Assessment Date 17-May-2017 at 13:31"`

`list(datefinder.find_dates(string.lower()))`
`#[datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 17, 13, 31)]`

Comment: agree that datefinder is heaps better than dateparser for ambiguous text

Comment: I agree that it's much better than `dateutil.parser.parse(text, fuzzy=True)`.
Gonna use it in my infrastructure utills.

Answer (score 4):

## Hands Down The Best Ways

There are two good modules on PyPI and GitHub, that make this task easier for us. Those are

1. **DATEFINDER** Module, useful for finding dates in strings of text.

Installation
`pip install datefinder`

### EXAMPLE

```py
import datefinder

input_string = "monkey 2010-07-10 love banana"
# a generator will be returned by the datefinder module. I'm typecasting it to a list. Please read the note of caution provided at the bottom.
matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(input_string))

if len(matches) > 0:
    # date returned will be a datetime.datetime object. here we are only using the first match.
    date = matches[0]
    print date
else:
    print 'No dates found'
```

SOURCE: Finny Abraham

2. **DATERPARSER**, extremely useful for scraping dates from an HTML file, in different lingual formats, supports Hijri and Jalali Calender as well. And supporters almost ***200+ Languages in Different Formats***

### Features

Generic parsing of dates in over ***200*** **language locales plus** numerous formats in a `language agnostic` fashion.
Generic parsing of relative dates like: `'1 min ago'`, `'2 weeks ago'`, `'3 months`, `1 week and 1 day ago'`, `'in 2 days'`, `'tomorrow'.`

#### Advanced Features

*Generic parsing of dates with time zones abbreviations* or UTC offsets like: `'August 14, 2015 EST', 'July 4, 2013 PST', '21 July 2013 10:15 pm +0500'.`
Date lookup in longer texts.
Support for non-Gregorian calendar systems. See Supported Calendars.
Extensive test coverage.

#### SOURCE CODE [Example]

```py
>>> parse('1 hour ago')
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 31, 23, 0)
>>> parse('Il ya 2 heures')  # French (2 hours ago)
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 31, 22, 0)
>>> parse('1 anno 2 mesi')  # Italian (1 year 2 months)
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 1, 0, 0)
>>> parse('yaklaşık 23 saat önce')  # Turkish (23 hours ago)
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 31, 1, 0)
>>> parse('Hace una semana')  # Spanish (a week ago)
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 25, 0, 0)
>>> parse('2小时前')  # Chinese (2 hours ago)
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 31, 22, 0)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided links for the libraries you mentioned. At least for the second one.

Comment: @Okroshiashvili https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/

Comment: I do not appreciate the clickbait title of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using Pygrok, you can define abstracted extensions to the Regular Expression syntax.

The custom patterns can be included in your regex in the format `%{PATTERN_NAME}`.

You can also create a label for that pattern, by separating with a colon: `%s{PATTERN_NAME:matched_string}`. If the pattern matches, the value will be returned as part of the resulting dictionary (e.g. `result.get('matched_string')`)

For example:

```
from pygrok import Grok

input_string = 'monkey 2010-07-10 love banana'
date_pattern = '%{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day}'

grok = Grok(date_pattern)
print(grok.match(input_string))
```

The resulting value will be a dictionary:

`{'month': '07', 'day': '10', 'year': '2010'}`

If the date_pattern does not exist in the input_string, the return value will be `None`. By contrast, if your pattern does not have any labels, it will return an empty dictionary `{}`

References:

- [pygrok (Github)](https://github.com/garyelephant/pygrok)
- [pygrok Preinstalled Definitions (Github)](https://github.com/garyelephant/pygrok/blob/master/pygrok/patterns/grok-patterns)

Comment: This lib ie very Python 2

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the [dateparser](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser) module, which may be slower than [datefinder](https://datefinder.readthedocs.io/) on free text but which should cover more potential cases and date formats, as well as a significant number of languages.

Answer (score 0):

**HARD MODE:**

If your dates are not separated by whitespace from surrounding text, combining `datefinder` with `wordninja` will solve this problem:

```
>>>import datefinder
>>>import wordninja
>>>example = '04.02.22ILeftMyHeartInSF ---> I Left My Heart In Sf - blah blah blah'
>>>list(datefinder.find_dates(' '.join(wordninja.split(example))))
[datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 22, 0, 0)]
```

Well sorta. That date was actually February 2004 not April 2022, but any tool would have to guess.

Just to be clear, this is what `wordninja` does to squishedtogethertext:

```
>>>wordninja.split(example)
['04', '02', '22', 'I', 'Left', 'My', 'Heart', 'In', 'SF', 'I', 'Left', 'My', 'Heart', 'In', 'Sf', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah']
```

Answer (score -9):

If you know the position of the date object in the string (for example in a log file), you can use .split()[index] to extract the date without fully knowing the format.

For example:

```
>>> string = 'monkey 2010-07-10 love banana'
>>> date = string.split()[1]
>>> date
'2010-07-10'
```