# Extracting date from a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, parsing, date, fuzzy

How can I extract the date from an arbitrary string such as "Joe Soap was born on 12 February 1981"?

Python has a wonderful fuzzy parsing functionality provided by `python-dateutil` as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python).

I'm looking for a library that provides the same type of functionality in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [date_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php)
, but if you know your date format, just use the regex to get what you want.

Comment: date_parse() is exactly what I was looking for and provides fuzzy date matching. Regex is not an option since the input format is unknown.