# Separating a date from a string in Python

Tags: python, string, date

Given a string with a date in an unknown format and other text, how can I separate the two?

```
>>dparser.parse("monkey 2010-07-10 love banana",fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 10, 0, 0)
```

from [Extracting date from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python)  is a step in the right direction, but what I want is the non-date text, for example:

```
date = 2010-07-10
str_a = 'monkey', str_b = 'love banana'
```

If the date string didn't have spaces in it, I could split the string and test each substring, but how about `'monkey Feb 20, 2015 loves 2014 bananas'`? `2014` and `2015` would both "pass" parse(), but only one of them is part of a date.

EDIT: there doesn't seem any reasonable way to deal with `'monkey Feb 20, 2015 loves 2014 bananas'`  That leaves `'monkey Feb 20, 2015 loves bananas'` or `'monkey 2/20/2015 loves bananas'` or `'monkey 20 Feb 2015 loves 2014 bananas'` or other variants as things parse() can deal with.

Comment: why 2015 is a year in your example while 2014 is not? The phrase is non-sense either way.

Comment: Fair point. Feb 20, 2015 is clearly a date, while 2014 is ambiguous.  If you run it through parse(...,fuzzy=True), it considers 2014 hours and minutes. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Perhaps I should examine the source for parse().

Comment: i'd start by trying a date parse at each offset ... if just one works, then use that ... if 2 or more offsets work, then you have a new problem.

Comment: @Skaperen split on spaces and consider any block that "passes" parse() as a date?  Or do you mean something else? BTW, for `Feb 20, 2015` each offset would pass, but the parts that work would be contiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the words , and for get ride of month names you can check that your strings not in `calendar.month_abbr` and `calendar.month_name`:

```
>>> import clalendar
>>> def word_find(s):
...       return [i for i in re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+',s) if i.capitalize() not in calendar.month_name and i.capitalize() not in calendar.month_abbr]
```

Demo:

```
>>> s1='monkey Feb 20, 2015 loves 2014 bananas'
>>> s2='monkey Feb 20, 2015 loves bananas'
>>> s3='monkey 2/20/2015 loves bananas'
>>> s4='monkey 20 Feb 2015 loves 2014 bananas'
>>> print word_find(s1)
['monkey', 'loves', 'bananas']
>>> print word_find(s2)
['monkey', 'loves', 'bananas']
>>> print word_find(s3)
['monkey', 'loves', 'bananas']
>>> print word_find(s4)
['monkey', 'loves', 'bananas']
```

and this :

```
>>> s5='monkey 20 January 2015 loves 2014 bananas'
>>> print word_find(s5)
['monkey', 'loves', 'bananas']
```

Comment: Consider Feb 20, 2015 or 20 February 2015. I could have a list of all full and abbreviated date strings, but that's tedious (and is may a date or not),  especially when parse() can recognize dates.

Comment: Kasra that's worked on everything I've tried so far.

Comment: Kasra, sorry, was doing a bit more testing, then got distracted trying to again figure out why @ shows up in your response to me and I can't get it in my response to you.

Comment: @foosion ;) its ok! because this is my answer and if you left comment here i 'll get a notification any way so there is no need to @ !

Comment: If I understand correctly, I see @ for your answers to me, but others don't.

Comment: @foosion no ...  J.F. Sebastian uses  @ in comment!

Comment: Also, you shouldn't define a function using the name of a built-in feature :-)

Comment: @foosion surely yes!;)

Answer (score 0):

To find date/time in a natural language text and to return their positions in the input text and thus allowing to get non-date text:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 import parsedatetime # $ pip install parsedatetime

 cal = parsedatetime.Calendar()
 for text in ['monkey 2010-07-10 love banana',
              'monkey Feb 20, 2015 loves 2014 bananas']:
     indices = [0]
     for parsed_datetime, type, start, end, matched_text in cal.nlp(text) or []:
         indices.extend((start, end))
         print([parsed_datetime, matched_text])
     indices.append(len(text))
     print([text[i:j] for i, j in zip(indices[::2], indices[1::2])])
```

#### Output

```
[datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 21, 20, 10), '2010']
['monkey ', '-07-10 love banana']
[datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 20, 0, 0), ' Feb 20, 2015']
[datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 21, 20, 14), '2014']
['monkey', ' loves ', ' bananas']
```

Note: `parsedatetime` failed to recognized `2010-07-10` as a date in the first string. `2010` and `2014` are recognized as a time (`20:10` and `20:14`) in both strings.

Comment: Doesn't 'failed to recognize' mean `parsedatetime` is not as good as recognizing valid date strings as `dateutil.parser.parse`?

Comment: @foosion: it depends on the input. It may be better at parsing human-readable date/time strings e.g., `cal.nlp('tomorrow')` works but `dateutil.parser.parse('tomorrow', fuzzy=True)` returns the default (wrong date).