# dateutil fuzzy parsing breaks when the input sentence contains the article 'a'

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I am searching for a way to extract date information from a string. After reading another SO thread ([Extracting date from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python)), it seems python-dateutil is an ideal solution. It has a fuzzy parsing method that is able to extract date info from any string:

Specifically, the method is

```
dateutil.parser.parse('your string here', fuzzy=True)
```

This works fine for many types of input strings containing a date, but I noticed that this method completely breaks when the input string contains the determiner 'a', as in sentences like

```
dateutil.parser.parse('a monkey on March 1, 2015', fuzzy=True)
dateutil.parser.parse("I ate a sandwich on March 1",fuzzy=True)
```

which all result in an error:

```
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

Does anyone know of a good workaround? Why does dateutil.parser break when the input contains the article "a"?

Comment: Works for me, which `dateutil` version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is a good workaround, but there is no error using `python-dateutil` < 2.4:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('a monkey on March 1, 2015', fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 0)
>>> parse("I ate a sandwich on March 1",fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 0)
>>> dateutil.__version__
'2.3'
```

FYI, here is what I get using `2.4` (latest currently):

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('a monkey on March 1, 2015', fuzzy=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format")
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

Consider reporting the problem by creating a new issue at the [dateutil bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dateutil).

Comment: Great. Thanks for this answer. I filed a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/dateutil/+bug/1428895

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue in 2.4 is due to a ValueError being fired when "a" for AM is matched without a corresponding hour.

In 2.3 and below, no such exception is fired.