# How to extract timing info like HH:MM:SS from a given list using for loop in Python without importing any module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
['From', 'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za', 'Sat', 'Jan', '5', '09:14:16', '2008',
 'From:', 'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za', 'From', 'louis@media.berkeley.edu',
 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '18:10:48', '2008', 'From:', 'louis@media.berkeley.edu',
 'From', 'zqian@umich.edu', 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '16:10:39', '2008', 'From:',
 'zqian@umich.edu', 'From', 'rjlowe@iupui.edu', 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '15:46:24',
 '2008', 'From:', 'rjlowe@iupui.edu', 'From', 'zqian@umich.edu', 'Fri', 'Jan',
 '4', '15:03:18', '2008', 'From:', 'zqian@umich.edu', 'From',
 'rjlowe@iupui.edu', 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '14:50:18', '2008', 'From:',
 'rjlowe@iupui.edu', 'From', 'cwen@iupui.edu', 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '11:37:30',
 '2008', 'From:', 'cwen@iupui.edu', 'From', 'cwen@iupui.edu', 'Fri', 'Jan', '4',
 '11:35:08', '2008', 'From:', 'cwen@iupui.edu', 'From', 'gsilver@umich.edu',
 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '11:12:37', '2008', 'From:', 'gsilver@umich.edu', 'From',
 'gsilver@umich.edu', 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '11:11:52', '2008', 'From:',
 'gsilver@umich.edu', 'From', 'zqian@umich.edu', 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '11:11:03',
 '2008', 'From:', 'zqian@umich.edu', 'From', 'gsilver@umich.edu', 'Fri', 'Jan',
 '4', '11:10:22', '2008', 'From:', 'gsilver@umich.edu', 'From',
 'wagnermr@iupui.edu', 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '10:38:42', '2008', 'From:',
 'wagnermr@iupui.edu', 'From', 'zqian@umich.edu', 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '10:17:43',
 '2008', 'From:', 'zqian@umich.edu', 'From', 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk', 'Fri',
 'Jan', '4', '10:04:14', '2008', 'From:', 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk', 'From',
 'gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '09:05:31', '2008',
 'From:', 'gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com', 'From', 'david.horwitz@uct.ac.za',
 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '07:02:32', '2008', 'From:', 'david.horwitz@uct.ac.za',
 'From', 'david.horwitz@uct.ac.za', 'Fri', 'Jan', '4', '06:08:27', '2008',
 'From:', 'david.horwitz@uct.ac.za', 'From', 'david.horwitz@uct.ac.za',]
```

Is there any of extracting a string of specific type like hh:mm:ss from a list?
I want to extract this information without importing any module.

Comment: Did you check python's datetime to get time from string?

Comment: Alternatively you can use regular expressions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting date from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: You're more likely to get better help if you show that you've put some effort into this. People are usually more willing to help fix failing code than generate code from nothing.

Answer (score 2):

RegEx way:

```
>>> [i for i in your_list if re.match('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', i)]
['09:14:16', '18:10:48', '16:10:39', 
 '15:46:24', '15:03:18', '14:50:18', 
 '11:37:30', '11:35:08', '11:12:37', 
 '11:11:52', '11:11:03', '11:10:22', 
 '10:38:42', '10:17:43', '10:04:14', 
 '09:05:31', '07:02:32', '06:08:27', 
 '04:49:08', '04:33:44', '04:07:34', 
 '19:51:21', '17:18:23', '17:07:00', 
 '16:34:40', '16:29:07', '16:23:48']
>>>
```

Comment: It's useful.But I want to find a way without importing any module.For this I have to "import re" .Just using list,tuple,string and dictionary methods.I tried finding ":" in list but that didnot work.

Comment: @user3400176 why can't you import any modules? `re` is part of the standard library...

Answer (score 1):

RegExp would be the obvious option here, **but** we could emulate some checks:

- string length 8
- occurrence of two colon signs
- *integer*-able parts after split (hh, mm, ss)
- hours less than 24
- minutes and seconds less than 60

better define a function here:

```
def hms(str):
  if len(str) != 8:
    return False
  parts = str.split(':')
  if len(parts) != 3:
    return False
  try:
    parts = [int(part) for part in parts]
  except ValueError as e:
    return False
  return parts[0] < 24 and parts[1] < 60 and parts[2] < 60
```

and feed it into the builtin [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
filter(hms, big_data)
```

or cram them in a `lambda` for a one liner version:

```
filter(lambda x: len(x) == 8 and len(x.split(':')) == 3 and int(x.split(':')[0]) < 24 and int(x.split(':')[1]) < 60 and int(x.split(':')[2]) < 60, big_data)
```