# Extract date from string in python

Tags: python, string, date, slice

How can I extract "20151101" (as string) from "Campaign on 01.11.2015"?

I have read this one:
[Extracting date from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python)
. But I am getting stuck when converting from Match object to string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With minor tweaks in the aforementioned post, you can get it to work.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

text = "Campaign on 01.11.2015"

match = re.search(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}', text)
date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%d.%m.%Y').date()
print str(date).replace("-", "")
20151101
```

Answer (score 1):

a slightly more robust regex: `.*?\b(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})\b`

(*nn*/*nn*/*nnnn* format with word boundaries)

replace string:`\3\2\1`

[<kbd>demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/mS3xK7/4)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, using `re.sub()`:

```
import re

s = "Campaign on 01.11.2015"

new_s = re.sub(r"Campaign on (\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)", r'\3\2\1', s)

print new_s
```

And another, using `re.match()`:

```
import re

s = "Campaign on 01.11.2015"

match = re.match(r"Campaign on (\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)", s)
new_s = match.group(3)+match.group(2)+match.group(1)

print new_s
```

Answer (score 1):

With magic of list.

```
In [15]: ''.join(a.split()[-1].split('.')[::-1])
Out[15]: '20151101'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets get crazy : D

```
       "".join(reversed(a.split()[-1].split(".")))
```