# Python extract date with different formats from a string

Tags: python, string, date, extract, python-dateutil

I tried package dateutil to extract date part from string. It works good if the exact date included in the string, like:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
try: 
    date = parse(string, fuzzy=True)
    print(str(date)[:10])
except ValueError:
    print("no date in text")

string = "an example of date:8 march 2019"
output: 2019-03-08

string = "an example of date: 2019/3/8"
output: 2019-03-08

string = "an example of pure string"
output: no date in text
```

But when a number is included in string instead of date, it goes wrong and considers it as a date:

```
string = "an example of wrong date: 8"

output: 2022-03-08
```

My question here is, how can I use this package or similar packages to solve this problem. There are some posts related to extracting dates, like [Extract date from string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192942/extract-date-from-string-in-python), but they have not covered this topic and they work for specific date format.

Your help much appreciated!

Comment: BTW, it would be good to use different name for a string than `string`. But I get it you use it to suggest the type.

Comment: Yes, you are right, just only showing the type.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to exploit the powerful ability of `dateutil` module to parse free-form dates but the default variety of dates it attempts to parse and the default normalization rules (using the *current* month/year when it is missing from the date) is not what you need.

One of the things you can do, is *not to attempt* parsing the value as a date using `dateutil` if it is parseable as integer value or when no digit is in the string to be parsed.

So my suggestion to satisfy these two pre-conditions (and you can extend the list therefore eliminating the default misinterpretations of `dateutil` in your case):

```
import re
from dateutil.parser import parse
try: 
    v = int(string)
    print("Seems like integer.")
except ValueError:  # requires that the date does not parse as proper int
    if re.search( r'\d', string) is not None:  # requires a digit in the string 
        try:
           date = parse(string, fuzzy=True)
           print(str(date)[:10])
        except ValueError:
           print("no date in text")
    else:
        print("Can't parse")
```

Comment: Thanks Sophros for the answer, however it looks like it does not produce any output, please try for string = "today 8" or "today 8 nov 2022" . The first one is just an integer and the second one is a date.

Comment: This is not true. "today 8" - it is a string and an integer.

Comment: I mean your code does not give any output/result for any input; I tried it in jupyter notebook. Could you please test your code for some input like "today 8" or "today 8 nov 2022" or those input examples mentioned in the original question?

Comment: Indeed this was an obvious misuse in the `re.search` - I swapped the pattern and the string to search for the pattern in the arguments. Corrected.