# There are 3 dataframes in pandas, each with diffrent date formats. How to make it uniform?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 3 dataframes in pandas as csv files:

1. Earthquake data in year-month-day all integers (2016-01-16).
2. Solar eclipse data-month(string-june etc)-day-month (both integers-June,28,1908).
3. Lunar eclipse data-year-month(string)-day integer (1901,May 3).

How do I make it a uniform format for me to merge the data?

Comment: Sir? Who are you talking to? There are women here too. Also, where is your data? I want to see your data, not an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
dparser.parse(STRING, fuzzy=True)
```

In your case

```
dparser.parse(dataframe.value, fuzzy=True)
```

For detail Check [STACKOVERFLOW LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python)