# parse datetime string with extra characters

Tags: python

I have a datetime field with a really silly format:

`2016423123`

where `2016` is the year, `4` is the month, `23` is the day, and `123` is irrelevant.

Does the `format` parameter of `datetime.strptime` support directives (like a regex) to ignore characters in the input string?

I know it is possible to just remove the extra characters and then feed the result to the parser, but I have a problem where I have several possible formats (not my invention...), and I was thinking of using try/catch to parse them.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

If the last 3 characters of your string are irrelevant, skip it during the conversion of your string to `datetime` object using *string slicing*. For example:

```
>>> my_str[:-3]
'2016423'
```

Here is the usage with `datetime.strptime`:

```
>>> my_str = '2016423123'
>>> from datetime import datetime

#                             v removing last 3 characters from string
>>> datetime.strptime(my_str[:-3], '%Y%m%d')
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 23, 0, 0)
```

Other examples, with different combination of single/double digit month/day:

```
>>> my_str = '20160423123'
>>> datetime.strptime(my_str[:-3], '%Y%m%d')
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 23, 0, 0)

>>> my_str = '2016043123'
>>> datetime.strptime(my_str[:-3], '%Y%m%d')
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 3, 0, 0)

>>> my_str = '201643123'
>>> datetime.strptime(my_str[:-3], '%Y%m%d')
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 3, 0, 0)

>>> my_str = '2016123123'
>>> datetime.strptime(my_str[:-3], '%Y%m%d')
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 3, 0, 0)
```