# Find the valid date between two tags

Tags: python, html, regex, date

Given an unstructured HTML text that contains some date values in the format '%b %d' with some constraints (see below) which approach would you consider as most appropriate:

- Go with regix?
- Parse manually?
- Take some python date libraries?

This is the extract of the HTML text:

```
text = '...some text ...>Jan 29 AMC<...some text ...'
```

And I am looking to extract the part:

- starting with an >
- then 3 letters following (i.e. the month)
- then a blank
- then 2 digits
- then the word AMC or BMO
- and then the <

Comment: Please provide what you have attempted.  As written, your question seems to be asking for the community to write the code for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting date from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It was definitely not the purpose to let others write code for me. I struggled for a while with this problem and I am very sure I am not alone with this task. Reformulated question so solutions can be beneficial for the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this regex :

```
<.*?>(\w{3}\s\d{2}\s(AMC|BMO))
```

* Note that the pattern can get you non-month pattern! otherwise you have to set them manually.

```
<.*?>((Jan|Feb|....)\s\d{2}\s(AMC|BMO))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wUEL23/1)

**Python code :**

```
import re 

reg = r'<.*?>(\w{3}\s\d{2}\s(AMC|BMO))'
text = '<...some text ...>Jan 29 AMC</...some text ...>'
Res = re.findall(reg,text)
if len(Res) != 0:
    for r in Res:
        print(r[0])
```

**Or**

```
import re 

reg = r'<.*?>(\w{3}\s\d{2}\s(AMC|BMO))'
text = '<...some text ...>Jan 29 AMC</...some text ...>'
Res = re.match(reg,text)
if Res:
    print ('Valid')
```

Comment: Awesome, very good. Also link https://regex101.com/r/wUEL23/1 ("Demo") ist very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [dateutil.parser()](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c) as explained in [this answewr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3276459/225020) to the question I marked as a duplicate.

```
import dateutil.parser as DateParser
from datetime import datetime

text = '...sometext...>Jan 29 AMC<...sometext...'
parsed_date = DateParser.parse(text, fuzzy=True)
print(parsed_date)
#2019-01-29 00:00:00
```

**Note**
*This does not take into concern the pattern matching you mentioned but does get you a date, this will also return multiple dates if it finds multiple dates. But it does do some guessing.*