# Extracting dates in any format from a pandas column (the date is a part of a longer string)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract dates in any format from a pandas column (the date is a part of a longer string).

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python) answer which does it outside of pandas, but I'm not sure how to use that to do it in a pandas column.

The dates can be in various formats, for example:

```
footballer, born October 1989
footballer, born 1900s
footballer, born 29 December 1987
Brazilian footballer, born 1983
31/02/1901
16 May 2019
```

Is it possible to have any date format and parts of dates as a pandas column with a date type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using the approach from the linked answer:

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
s.apply(lambda x: dparser.parse(x,fuzzy=True).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Although `dparser` can't of course cope with all possibilities: in the sample data you'll have to change `footballer, born 1900s` to `footballer, born 1900's`, otherwise parse will complain that second must be in 0..59

If you need exception handling, you'll have to define a regular function as lambdas can't handle try/except:

```
def myparser(x):
    try:
       return dparser.parse(x,fuzzy=True)
    except:
       return None

s.apply(lambda x: myparser(x))
```

This will insert `NaT` values for wrong dates (or you can provide a 'default date' if you like):

```
0    1989-10-12
1           NaT
2    1987-12-29
3    1983-07-12
4           NaT
5    2019-05-16
```

Comment: it appears `pd.to_datetime` does not have any option for `infer_datetime_format` to be applied per instance - so this may also be your fastest obvious option.

Comment: @modesitt and infer_datetime_format won't handle cases when other text (footballer etc) is in the string

Comment: Is this for a specific column? `df['birth_date'] = df.apply(lambda x: dparser.parse(x, fuzzy=True).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))` gives me a `TypeError: ('Parser must be a string or character stream, not Series', 'occurred at index subject')` error

Comment: @Superdooperhero You try to apply the function to the whole dataframe, apply it to a specific column: if you have a dataframe with a column `Strings` then use this to insert a new column `birth_date`: `df['birth_date']=df.Strings.apply(lambda x: dparser.parse(x,fuzzy=True))`.

Comment: @Stef: Thanks that fixed the previous error, but now I get this error: `ValueError: ('String does not contain a date:', 'footballer')`, sorry I forgot to mention that some rows does not contain a date but instead just a random string without a date.

Comment: @Superdooperhero invalid or unknown string formats without a date will raise this ValueError, see my edit above for error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it can't recognize a row as containing a date it will return 1/1/1 , if the date is not complete with month and date will assume january 1st, but you can change it, by adjust the default.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

l = ['footballer, born October 1989',
'footballer, born 1900s',
'footballer, born 29 December 1987',
'Brazilian footballer, born 1983',
'31/02/1901',
'16 May 2019']

df  = pd.Series(l, name='strings')

def get_dates(series):
my_list =[]
for i in range(len(series)):
    for j in range(len(series[i])):
        try:
            my_list.append(parse(series[i][j:],default=datetime(1, 1, 1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
            break                
        except:
            pass
return pd.Series(my_list)    


get_dates(df)

0    1989-10-01
1    0001-01-01
2    1987-12-29
3    1983-01-01
4    1901-01-02
5    2019-05-16
dtype: object
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a pandas column with the dates not a list.

Comment: I updated the function to return a series instead of a list