# How to extract dates from filename in Python when there are two dates? And how do I convert to day of year?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a list of files that I'm lopping through that contain two dates in the filename. How do I extract each date and store it into a variable? And how do I convert it to day of year?

The code I have isn't working because I can't extract the month/day due to some months leading with zero. The code I have is:

```
sstDataFile=AQUA_MODIS.20100101_20100131.L3m.MO.SST.sst.4km.nc

    year1=int(sstDataFile[11:15])
    day1=int(sstDataFile[15:19])
    year2=int(sstDataFile[20:24])
    day2=int(sstDataFile[24:27])
    
    print(year1)
    print(year2)
    print (day1)
    print(day2)
    if year1%4==0:
        decYr1 = year1 + day1/366.0
    else:   
        decYr1 = year1 + day1/365.0

    if year2%4==0:
        decYr2 = year2 + day2/366.0
    else:    
        decYr2 = year2 + day2/365.0
    
    decYr=0.5*(decYr1+decYr2) #decimal year between the composite start and end points
```

Comment: use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: ok but how do I extract the dates? That's the main issue I'm having

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python you may have to split your string in two before using solutions from this link, should be easy if all filenames follow the same pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to parse and perform operations with dates in python:

First you need to manipulate the string a bit to extract the part that has to do with the date. Assuming that all your strings come in the same format (i.e. `'SOMETHING.date1_date2.SOMETHINGELSE...'`):

```py
full_string = 'AQUA_MODIS.20100101_20100131.L3m.MO.SST.sst.4km.nc'
date1, date2 = full_string.split('.')[1].split('_')
print(date1, date2)
```

> 20100101 20100131

Now that we have extracted the dates we need to convert them to datetime format. Your two strings are in the following format `YYYYMMDD`. Somehow we need to tell datetime that that is the format it should be using. You can see more details about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp). In our case it should look like this:

```py
fmt='%Y%m%d'  # %Y --> YYYY
              # %m --> MM
              # %d --> DD

date1 = datetime.strptime(date1, fmt)
date2 = datetime.strptime(date2, fmt)

print(date1, date2)
```

> 2010-01-01 00:00:00 2010-01-31 00:00:00

From what I understand you want to find the "average" year in decimals. Datetime allows you to perform operations on dates. I think the best way to do this in your case is:

```py
avg_date = datetime.fromtimestamp((date1.timestamp() + date2.timestamp()) / 2)

print(avg_date)
```

> 2010-01-16 00:00:00

Finally, you want to represent the date as a fraction of the year:

```py
y = avg_date.year
m = (avg_date.month - 1) / 12
d = (avg_date.day - 1) / 365

result = y + m + d
print(result)
```