# Split pandas column into two by a number(containing time)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
col_1
Agent AB 7:00 AM
Agent AB 7:00 AM
Cust XY 8:00 AM
Cust XY 9:00 AM
Agent AB 11:00 AM
```

I want to split it into 2 columns such that the time gets split into a new column.

Expected Output:

```
col_1        col_2
Agent AB     7:00 AM
Agent AB     7:00 AM
Cust XY      8:00 AM
Cust XY      9:00 AM
Agent AB     11:00 AM
```

I researched and found out that this can be done using: string slicing.

Something like:

```
df['col_2'] = df['col_1'].str[-8:-1]
```

Is there a better way to do it??

Comment: you can use regex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting date from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
import pandas as pd
df["col_1"].str.extract(r"^(.*?)\s+(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M)$").rename(columns={0: "col_1", 1: "col_2"})
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/gTFotO/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^(.*?)                      ##Creating 1st capturing group, matching from starting of value and doing a non-greedy match(till followed by spaces 1 or more occurrences).
\s+                         ##Mentioning spaces 1 or more spaces here.
(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M)$    ##Creating 2nd capturing group, matching digits 1 or 2 numbers followed by : matching 1 or 2 digits followed by space and AM/PM.
```

Output with shown samples is coming as follows:

```
      col_1    col_2
0  Agent AB  7:00 AM
1  Agent AB  7:00 AM
2   Cust XY  8:00 AM
```

Comment: much more robust!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 It's giving me NaN's in both the columns :(

Comment: @ShubhamR, oh, is your actual df is same as shown samples only? Or its different from shown one, kindly do let me know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yeah, it was a sample dataset. The code given by Mustafa works fine on the dataset though

Comment: @ShubhamR, with your shown dataset this has worked fine for me, not sure but regex looks for same kind of values which you have shown in inputs samples.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yeah, I looked at the same, don't know why this doesn't work. Instead of "Agent AB" replace with "MANAU BADA 6:58 AM " and "Cust XY" with "WONG AI NEIG 6:58 AM "

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 and with different time. One more thing to observe is the trailing whitespaces

Comment: @ShubhamR, could you please do give one line for which it isn't working, I need to check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231605/discussion-between-shubham-r-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @ShubhamR, Here is [regex demo for your 2nd shown samples](https://regex101.com/r/b3v9k5/1) which shows my solution's regex worked fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

```
df["col_1"].str.extract(r"^(\D+)(.+)$").rename(columns={0: "col_1", 1: "col_2"})
```

gives

```
       col_1     col_2
0  Agent AB    7:00 AM
1  Agent AB    7:00 AM
2   Cust XY    8:00 AM
3   Cust XY    9:00 AM
4  Agent AB   11:00 AM
```

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/jBORpq/1) is looking for consecutive non-digits `(\D+)` and then the first digit on is captured with `(.+)`. We then rename columns.