# Python - Select text in a string until find date greater than another date

Tags: string, date, compare

I'm stuck with this thing (I'm a beginner in Python and it's become too complicated for me). I searched for days but never found any solution anywhere.

I have an `History_string` like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
Jeu. 17/06/2021 - 16:12:48


Sent email 

----------------------------------------------------------------

Mer. 16/06/2021 - 11:34:43


meeting today

----------------------------------------------------------------
Lun. 14/06/2021 - 20:02:34


phone call today

----------------------------------------------------------------
```

and I would like to insert another string which contains another interaction with the customer, lets say `New_interaction`:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
Mar. 15/06/2021 - 17:34:45


New interaction
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is **searching the `History_string` until it founds a date less than `New_interaction` and insert `New_interaction` right there**.

So the result would be :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
Jeu. 17/06/2021 - 16:12:48


Sent email 

----------------------------------------------------------------

Mer. 16/06/2021 - 11:34:43


meeting today

----------------------------------------------------------------

Mar. 15/06/2021 - 17:34:45


New interaction

----------------------------------------------------------------

Lun. 14/06/2021 - 20:02:34


phone call today

----------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hour is always the same? Could you also shared what you have already tried?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your interest, no the hour isn't always the same but the date format is. I already tried to deal with things like History_string.find(<New_interaction_date) . I already know how to select some part of a string using [0: end of string] but what i'm looking for is not a match it's a comparison and don't know how to tell my .find to find less or greater than something. I hope i make myself clear enough

Comment: Well, you would have to convert your date time string into a date time object in order to compare. U can use the datetime library in python for that. Since your time could be different the comparison also has to take this into account. Give it a go, if you dont manage, post your code and i will try to fix it for you.

Comment: OK but how can I isolate the date as my string contain text + dates ?

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python