# Only print the date in a string

Tags: python, string, date, datetime

This is my string

```
word = " Saturday Fortune 08-09-2022 (4872) Draw Numbers "
```

But I only want to print the date in the string like this

```
'08-09-2022'
```

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting date from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Should use a **regular expression** to find that part in the string. Something like:

```py
import re
match = re.search(r'\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}', word)
```

This already seems to be answered as a subproblem in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276180/extracting-date-from-a-string-in-python).